# C: Vigenere cipher compiles but segmentation error - pointers?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, vigenere

I'm getting a segmentation error somewhere in this code, though it compiles successfully. The code is to iterate repeatedly through a key to encipher a plaintext word. I'm assuming it's pointer-related but I don't know how to fix it.

Also: is that an appropriate way to express a negative for `isalpha`? It didn't throw an error. It did throw an error when I tried to use `==FALSE` after it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    if ((argc<2) || (argc>2) || (!isalpha(argv)))//exits if non-alpha key or < or > than 2 command line inputs 
    {
        printf("Please enter your single word key"); //prompts for appropriate key
        return 1; 
    }

    if(argc==2) // requires two command line inputs with non-integer key to continue
    {
        printf("plaintext:");      //Printed on terminal before word to be enciphered 
        char* word = GetString();  //Prompts user to enter word required to be enciphered

        printf("ciphertext:");   

    char* key = (argv[1]);  //key = initial user command line entry   


    int i = 0;  
    int k = 0;     //defines characters in key   

    for(i=0; i<strlen(word); i++)    //iterates through word entered by user as plaintext
    {   

        if(isalpha(key[k]))
        {

            if(isupper(word[i]))    //if original characters are uppercase 
            {
                int cipher = (word[i] + key[k] -65) % 26 + 65; 
                printf("%c", cipher);

            }
            else if(islower(word[i]))  //if original characters are lowercase
            {
                int cipher = (word[i] + key[k] - 97) % 26 + 97; 
                printf("%c", cipher);
            }        
            else    //for all other types of characters
            {
                printf("%c", word[i]); 
            } 

        }    
        else if(!isalpha(key[k]))
        {
            return 1;
        }


        if (word[i]==strlen(word)) //if reaches end of plaintext word
        {
            printf("\n");   //print a new line and exit
            return 1;      
        }    

        else if(word[i]<strlen(word))  //if haven't reached end of word, increment k 
        {
            k++;
        }    

        if (key[k]==strlen(key))
        {
            k = 0;
        }    

    }
    printf("\n"); 

    }

}
```

Comment: `!isalpha(argv)` ==> `!isalpha(argv[1][0])`. Please enable compiler warnings and deal with them all.

Comment: Also `if(argc==2)` is a tautology: you already know that.

Comment: Whenever you have a program that segfaults, try [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `word[i]==strlen(word)` ... There is meaningless in comparing the lengths of strings and a letter. If this meant `i == stelen(word)`, This never become true in the loop of `for(i=0; i<strlen(word); i++)`.

Comment: For a given key and word what should the output be?

Comment: BLUEPIXY: With that line I was trying to create a way to exit after enciphering to the end of the plaintext word. I guess that's dumb here as the for loop stops it at the end of the word anyway.                                  In other cases, where there is no loop, how do I express "if you've reached the end of the word" ?

Comment: Weather Vane: Part of the exercise is that the code has to exit (return 1) if the keyword the user enters contains numbers as well as letters. Will your suggested modification do this? I'm sorry but I've never seen that before and I am new to programming. I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Chimera: The key word and plaintext word is supplied by the user. The key is applied, letter by letter, to the plaintext word and applies the equations as they go in order to encipher them. Vigenere is a cipher from the year 1533. It's like a Caesar Cipher with an extra layer. The inner 'if' statements Caesar Cipher works properly but I'm struggling with the outer iteration through the keyword. The key has to repeat if it's shorter than the word.